# How to map RAWINPUT HID event data to get touch point coordinates

Tags: windows, hid, raw-input

I'm trying to use the [Windows RAWINPUT API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and WM_INPUT messages to get raw touch event data for multi-touch input. 
Note, WM_TOUCH was already tried but did not provide the needed performance.

I got RAWINPUT working, so a device is registered and receives messages for touch events in a raw format of 63 bytes. 
How can this vendor-specific raw input data for those events be converted / mapped into vendor-independent data in order to retrieve the touch points coordinates safely for different device types?

There must be a generic way to map that raw data to structured information. I assume through retrieving the schema of the data format. 
Any pointers in the right direction or code snippets would be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you show your codes?

Comment: There's not much code to share. The raw hid data is retrieved. That's expected and works fine. I'm just clueless how to map / convert the raw byte array to get the touch point coordinates. Here's some sample code: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/381673/Using-the-RawInput-API-to-Process-MultiTouch-Digit 
But there must be a generic way to map the raw data to a common format.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I've read that we can use GetRawInputDeviceInfo with RIDI_PREPARSEDDATA, but then the same problem - I don't know how to decode this PHIDP_PREPARSED_DATA data.

Answer (score 1):

There are some great resources here http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsTouch and some code examples here http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=WindowsTouch&DownloadId=5038

Comment: Thanks, but that stuff is all about WM_TOUCH and not RAWINPUT / WM_INPUT which is a level below. WM_TOUCH was already tried but did not provide the needed performance. I edited my question to make this clearer.